# Hashing Elements by Mid-Square

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable

I'm making a hash function for a hash table of size 10 (indexes 0-9), and hashing elements using mid-square method.
The Problem is I'm confused whether i should use 1 middle digit or 2 digits then taking mod 10 of it.
The problem is if I choose to take 2 mid digit then taking mod 10, this method will fail if the squared number has 3 digits. Which two digits will I take then?
and if I choose to have 1 middle digit, then I'll have problem taking mid digit when squared number has even number of digits. I know in this situation both of the mid two element are made from contribution of all elements of the original number. 
Right now, I'm going with {floor(n/2+1)}th digit. This way it works for three digit squared number, and when the squared number has even no. of digits, it's taking the later digit of the middle two.
I wanna know what more efficient approach of doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: What you're doing is reasonable.  Say the squared number has digits A B C D, it's meaningless to talk of taking "C D" because after `% 10` you just have D anyway, so take it directly.  If there's an odd number of digits, clearly use the middle one.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that the correct way to mid square hash is to use 1 digit if the length of the resulting square is odd, if it's even then use the middle 2 digits.